# How to get WinJS.xhr not to cache responses in Windows 8

Tags: xmlhttprequest, windows-8

I have no control over the web service I aam calling so adding header attributes is not an option. I have tried adding a timestamp in the url but that did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A total hack would be to add random parameters to the URL request..

```
var URL = URL + "&rnd=" + someRandomString
```

The parameters will be ignored on the server end, but WinJS.xhr will think you are making a new request.  Sorry that I don't have more time to dig in and see if there is a better way... but that was the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: As I said in the description I have tried that and it did not work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

You could add the `If-Modified-Since` header to the headers property of the options parameter to the `WinJS.xhr` function.

```
WinJS.xhr({ 
    url: "http://www.microsoft.com",
    headers: {
        "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 27 Mar 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
    } })
    .done(function complete(result) {
        // Report download.
        xhrDiv.innerText = "Downloaded the page";
        xhrDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
});
```

[Check here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868281.aspx)

Comment: Yep, also tried that and it did not work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Worked for me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868281.aspx